# Define & Iniitialise flash variable in main

Tags: c, flash, msp430

Struggling with what is probably a simple command to define and initialise a flash variable in main.c (IAR Embedded Workbench / TI MSP430F)

I have a flash routine In a separate C file (Battery_Store.c) which takes in a variable (from main) and stores it in a set location. The flash routines function.

```
void Set_Battery_Store( unsigned int Battery_Status )
    {

            Flash_Start() ;
            Flash_Erase_Segment( (unsigned int *)&Battery_Status ) ;
            Flash_Write_Word( (unsigned int *)&Battery_Status, Battery_Status ) ;
            Flash_Finish() ;
    }
```

I define the variable and initialise it in the same C file

```
const volatile unsigned int Battery_Status @ 0x1070 = 1 ;
```

and in the .h

```
extern const volatile unsigned int Battery_Status ;
```

But of course every time I call Battery_Store from main (System_Flags.Battery_Status is a different variable handled in main). i.e.

```
Set_Battery_Store (System_Flags.Battery_Status)  ;
```

Battery_Status becomes 1 again, presumably because of the

```
const volatile unsigned int Battery_Status @ 0x1070 = 1 ;
```

How do I set and initialise Battery_Status from within main.c (and not within Battery_Store.c and Battery_Store.h) and have Battery_Store.c refer to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Battery_Status` parameter of the `Set_Battery_Store` function is a parameter, so it lives on the stack. So when using `&Battery_Status`, this function never actually accesses any flash memory.

Give either the parameter or the global variable a different name.